# Reading strings of files

Tags: c, file

I am really newbie in C and I want create a program that reads two input files which are only include strings. I have created for its related file's strings. I have dealing with some problem and I couldn't figure out, there is some segmentation fault in there. (asked by-ua)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct linked_list {
    char my_data[256];
    struct linked_list *next_it;
} node_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    /*
    if(argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Requiring 2 input 1 output file name to start!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }*/

    FILE *my_s;
    FILE *my_f;
    // FILE *my_o;
    bool mybool = true;
    int my_ch; // our char to read
    char my_buffer[256];
    bool check_all = true;

    node_t *set_a = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node_t *set_b = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    my_f = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // first textfile to read
    my_s = fopen(argv[2], "r"); // second textfile to read

    if (my_f != NULL && my_s != NULL) {
        while (fgetc(my_f) != EOF && mybool != false && check_all != false) {
            my_ch = fgetc(my_f);
            int i = 0;
            while (my_ch >= 0) {
                my_buffer[i++] = my_ch;
                my_ch = fgetc(my_f);
            }
            strcpy(set_a->my_data, my_buffer);
            if (feof(my_f)) {
                mybool = false;
            } else {
                set_a->next_it = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                set_a = set_a->next_it;
            }
        }
        mybool = false;
        printf("First File Copy Done!\n");
        while (fgetc(my_s) != EOF && mybool != true && check_all != false) {
            my_ch = fgetc(my_s);
            int i = 0;
            while (my_ch >= 0) {
                my_buffer[i++] = my_ch;
                my_ch = fgetc(my_s);
            }
            strcpy(set_b->my_data, my_buffer);
            if (feof(my_s)) {
                check_all = false;
            } else {
                set_b->next_it = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                set_b = set_b->next_it;
            }
        }
        printf("Second File Copy Done!\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read from %s and %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    }

    while (set_a != NULL) {
        int j = 0;
        printf("No: %d, Var: %s",j++, set_a->my_data);
        node_t *set_c = set_a;
        set_a = set_a->next_it;
        free(set_c);
    }
    while (set_b != NULL) {
        int j = 0;
        printf("No: %d, Var: %s",j++, set_b->my_data);
        node_t *set_c = set_b;
        set_b = set_b->next_it;
        free(set_c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code was not indented.  Learn to indent the code and use spaces to make the code readable.  Study the way I reformatted it and do that as you type, it will help you avoid many silly bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- You initialize your list with an uninitialized first node.  There is no way to test anything in this node... Why not initialize an empty list as `NULL`.
- You test for end of file by reading the next byte from each file, but you do not store this byte... so it gets lost.  Later you check for `feof(my_s)`, but this function does not do what you think it does. It is much better to check is `fgetc()` returns `EOF`, but store the byte it read.
- Why do you start every local variable name with `my` or `my_`, this is not helping, just use the short names, they are not supposed to designate anything global anyway.
- You do not keep a pointer to the head of each list, you set `set_a` and `set_b` to point to the next node, there is just no way to find the head of the lists anymore.
- You reset `j` to `0` in each iteration of the print and free loop, all nodes will print with number `0`.
- You should use functions to load, print and free the lists, to avoid repeating the same code twice.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct linked_list {
    char *data;
    struct linked_list *next;
} node_t;

node_t *load_lines(const char *filename) {
    node_t *head = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        char buffer[256];
        size_t i = 0;
        int c;
        node_t **tailp = &head;

        for (;;) {
            c = fgetc(fp);
            if (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
                if (i < sizeof(buffer) - 1) {
                    buffer[i++] = c;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (i > 0) {
                buffer[i] = '\0';
                /* allocate a new node */
                *tailp = malloc(sizeof(**tailp));
                (*tailp)->next = NULL;
                (*tailp)->data = strdup(buffer);
                tailp = &(*tailp)->next;
                i = 0;
            }
            if (c == EOF) {
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return head;
}

void print_word(node_t *np) {
    int j = 0;
    while (np != NULL) {
        printf("No: %d, Var: %s", j++, np->data);
        np = np->next;
    }
}

void free_words(node_t *np) {
    while (np != NULL) {
        node_t *next = np->next;
        free(np->data);
        free(np);
        np = next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    /*
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Requiring 2 input 1 output file name to start!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }*/

    node_t *set_a, *set_b;

    if ((set_a = load_words(argv[1])) != NULL) {
        printf("First File Copy Done!\n");
    }
    if ((set_b = load_words(argv[2])) != NULL) {
        printf("Second File Copy Done!\n");
    }
    if (!set_a && !set_b) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read from %s and %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    }

    print_words(set_a);
    free_words(set_a);
    print_words(set_b);
    free_words(set_b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I have covered your notes, too. Best, -ua

Comment: Actually, this works really well but from my own example input file, code does not outputs the last line of string. (i.e. prints 24 out of 25, without last line). I think that last line of string is not in our linkedlist because at print_word part, it terminates after reaching NULL variable

Comment: The code above assumes that the file ends with a linefeed. If the last line of the file does not have a final `\n`, it is not added to the linked list.  I shall modify the code to handle this case, but it is preferable for all text files to have a final line feed.

Comment: @chqlie , I have dealing with new problem and I have put my new code by editing my question, you can see that in there. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @nerdguycs_b: please don't do this: post a new question. Modifying the question is only palatable to fix presentation and ambiguities.  If you have a new problem, it is time to ask a new question and stop dragging this discussion beyond its initial scope.

Comment: @chrqlie, I wanted to, but site does not give permission to ask a new question, so then, I have edited my question to get some proper answers.

Comment: @nerdguycs_b: alas. The presence of rules does not allow you to find ways to circumvent them.

Comment: @nerdguycs_b: what error does S.O. give you when you try and ask a new question?

Answer (score 0):

You are not pointing the tail of the two linked lists to 'NULL' after reaching the end of file and you are not maitaining the heads of each linked list. You change the head each time reading a string. So at final stage 'set_a' and 'set_b' become the last node without a NULL tail